# What is the name of this out-of-place rank order statistic?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, soft-question, terminology

I've just read [N-Gram-Based Text Categorization](http://odur.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/textcat.pdf) where the authors describe the following "out-of-place" rank order statistic based distance measure:

[image]

I think I have seen that before, but with another name. Does anybody recognize this?

Comment: I have seen 'derangements' used for a few different things (in combinatorics, magic tricks with cards, matching problems, permutation tests).. Similar to this, but not specifically in the context of 'ranks'.. Maybe others will have better suggestions.

Comment: I'm 95% sure I have seen this in one of my math classes (statistics, linear algebra or analysis), but I don't remember which one :-/ (It could also be that we didn't give it a name, though)

Comment: Added a couple of possibly useful 'tags'.